# limit the number of entries in the for loop

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model and ready-made data in a table. In this model, I added a new field and made a connection with another table.

And in order not to manually fill in these fields for each record, I want to create a migration that will automatically fill in this field for all records.

Relationship table has two fields: post_id and author_id.

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();

foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++ ) {
        $item = new PostAuthor();
        $item->setAttribute('post_id', $posts->id);
        $item->setAttribute('author_id', $i+1);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Now everything works so that the maximum number of author_id will be equal to the number of posts, i.e. for the first post it will be author_id: 1, for the second author_id: 1 and author_id: 2, and so on up to 6 author_id.

Can I limit the $index so that the maximum number here is 4, and when the author_id gets to 4, the loop starts over from 1?

Comment: Your explanation confuse me. How many posts have you in your data base? And what number is assigned to $index?

Comment: @ExecAssa there are 8 posts, $index is also equal to 8 respectively, the idea is to fill all existing posts, but the problem is that they are now assigned extra author_id

Comment: The code below does nothing more than reset $j at 0 when $j is greater than 4. What did you expect? Its very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$posts = Posts::find()->all();

foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
    for($i = 0; $j=0; $i < $index; $i++ ) {
        if ( $j > 4 ) {
        $j = 0;
        }
        $item = new PostAuthor();
        $item->setAttribute('post_id', $posts->id);
        $item->setAttribute('author_id', $j+1);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post a little based on your answer, but everything is not working as it should yet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).